# How to delete old neo4j data

Tags: neo4j

I have a graph database where each node has an ID assigned, and this ID is actually composed of a timestamp, so it is incremental.
I was thinking this way I could delete old data from the database like this:
`MATCH (n)
WHERE n.value < 1408684077231000000
WITH n LIMIT 1000
OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[r]-()
DELETE r,n RETURN COUNT(*)`

The problem is this is just too slow. Slower than inserting new data. `value` is indexed. Is there a better solution for discarding old data? Partitioning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it doesnt matter that `values` are indexed, since

```
WHERE n.value < 1408684077231000000
```

does not, and actually cannot, use index. its a pure match comparison, no mater of index. the use of index will be just to search for data in `MATCH` like

```
MATCH (n {value:1408684077231000000})
```

but there is one solution which comes to my mind for your situation: imagine you want to delete nodes older than some time, lets say a day (it will be rounded/ceiled down to a day). each day, you will create a helper node with some label `:Helper` which would have actually the timestamp value of that particular day. during the day, all **new created nodes** will have a relationship to that helper node.

later in the future, lets say in one year, you can search within just those helper nodes for those, which have the value less than you want, and delete all related nodes to them like this:

```
MATCH (n:Helper) //all helper nodes
WHERE n.value < 1408684077231000000 //some day in the past
WITH n  //all helper nodes with value less than the timestamp
MATCH n--del //find out all nodes to delete
WITH n, del
OPTIONAL MATCH del-[r]-() //now continue with your query above
DELETE n, r, del
RETURN count(*)
```

this will work for times rounded to days, if you need more strict times, you can create those helper nodes each hour, minute or so..

Comment: Then I would have huge graphs. Could that create problems?

Comment: considering the memory space no - before you had `value` on each node, now you have a relationship on each node + additional helper nodes (in case of days = just 365 helper nodes/year). in neo4j, a relationship takes less space than a property+its value. you will just have larger graph in mater of relations, but not in mater of memory space taken on the server. and since neo4j does not care much how many relations it has (except when 1 node has milions+ relationships), this proposed solution is fine.

Comment: you must think in graphs - if there is a way to decentralize your properties (i.e. timestamps on each node) into relationships, than its better to do so

Comment: But this way I will have 1 node with milions+ relationships, If I have milions+ new node/hour.

Comment: yes. but for such a graph there might not be a reasonable solution. maybe some hack with `neo4j-spatial`, where you would put timestamps instead of gps coordinates would help. or try to set up the `helper` nodes with shorter period - hours or decades of minutes. a day period was just an example.

Comment: or remember the timestamp of the node with the lowest id - `Match (n) RETURN Id(n) ORDER BY 1 LIMIT 1`, than simply erase all nodes with ids `Id(n) + 1 000 000`.

Comment: IDs are never reused?

Comment: hm, in versions under 2.0 i remember no (until specifically set to), but in the newer versions im not sure, and you are right - one should not rely on it on production. so do you have a graph with milions new nodes per hour?

Comment: About 1M per hour. I'll experiment with 20 minute nodes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60061/discussion-between-ulkas-and-milan).

Answer (score 0):

Queries based on properties are always slow, since all the candidate nodes (in this case all nodes in the graph) need to be read in order to decide if they should filtered out or not.

To achieve faster queries you should try to **limit the candidate nodes**. In general you can do this by leveraging labels and/or relationships.

If you want to do time based queries on your graph there seems to be a general consensus that using **time trees** work best. The queries for a specific time range will result in **traversing a sub graph**, thus heavily reducing query run time.

For an example of a time graph have a look at [this post by Michael Hunger](http://jexp.de/blog/2014/04/importing-forests-into-neo4j/).

Note: You don't need to go down to seconds if you only care about months or days. You can just build a pragmatic time tree down to the units you care about.

An auto-expire feature would be nice to have, but AFAIK this is not yet implemented.